# Firebase deploy Function "An unexpected error has occurred"

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am working with functions and everything was working fine, but after running the command **"npm install Blob --save"** I start to get "An unexpected error occurred" and couldn't load any more functions.

Tried removing node modules and installing again, updating firebase tools, uninstalling Blob dependency, but the error continues.

After that, I checked about the error in firebase-debug.log, and found the following messages:

**[debug] [functions] failed to list functions for project-name.**

**[debug] [functions] Some Cloud Functions regions were unreachable, please try again later.**

This is my console log

```
i  deploying functions
Running command: npm --prefix "$RESOURCE_DIR" run lint

> functions@ lint D:\DESKTOP\Trabajo\MyQuickQR\myfreeqr.com - Copy\functions
> eslint "src/**/*"

Running command: npm --prefix "$RESOURCE_DIR" run build

> functions@ build D:\DESKTOP\Trabajo\MyQuickQR\myfreeqr.com - Copy\functions
> tsc

+  functions: Finished running predeploy script.
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled...
+  functions: required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled
+  functions: required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled
i  functions: preparing functions directory for uploading...
i  functions: packaged functions (60.79 KB) for uploading

Error: An unexpected error has occurred.
```

Comment: Please try again, this should be resolved.